# how change local language in veeValidate by CDN install

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

i m installed veeValidate from CDN and add in my cshtml like that :

Vue.component('validation-provider', VeeValidate.ValidationProvider);

how change local language from en to fr or other?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it when declaring VeeValidate:

```
Vue.use(VeeValidate, {locale: 'fr'});//(or your locale of choice)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.
I made a mistake on the subject, the insalation of veevalidate is not with: Vue.component('validation-provider', VeeValidate.ValidationProvider); but with : <script src="~/lib/vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.full.js"></script> in _layout.cshtml....

Comment: Vue.use(VeeValidate, {locale: 'fr'}); dont work because i m not devlopping with  ES2015 syntax

Comment: i found a solution : VeeValidate.localize('fr', {
        code: 'fr',
        messages: {
            alpha: "Le champ {_field_} ne peut contenir que des lettres",
            alpha_num: "Le champ {_field_} ne peut contenir que des caractères alpha-numériques",
            alpha_dash: "Le champ {_field_} ne peut contenir que des caractères alpha-numériques, tirets ou soulignés",
            
        }
    });

Answer (score 0):

VeeValidate.localize('fr', {
code: 'fr',
messages: {
alpha: "Le champ {*field*} ne peut contenir que des lettres",
alpha_num: "Le champ {*field*} ne peut contenir que des caractères alpha-numériques",
alpha_dash: "Le champ {*field*} ne peut contenir que des caractères alpha-numériques, tirets ou soulignés",
alpha_spaces: "Le champ {*field*} ne peut contenir que des lettres ou des espaces",
between: "Le champ {*field*} doit être compris entre {min} et {max}",
confirmed: "Le champ {*field*} ne correspond pas",
digits: "Le champ {*field*} doit être un nombre entier de {length} chiffres",
dimensions: "Le champ {*field*} doit avoir une taille de {width} pixels par {height} pixels",
email: "Le champ {*field*} doit être une adresse e-mail valide",
excluded: "Le champ {*field*} doit être une valeur valide",
ext: "Le champ {*field*} doit être un fichier valide",
image: "Le champ {*field*} doit être une image",
integer: "Le champ {*field*} doit être un entier",
length: "Le champ {*field*} doit contenir {length} caractères",
max_value: "Le champ {*field*} doit avoir une valeur de {max} ou moins",
max: "Le champ {*field*} ne peut pas contenir plus de {length} caractères",
mimes: "Le champ {*field*} doit avoir un type MIME valide",
min_value: "Le champ {*field*} doit avoir une valeur de {min} ou plus",
min: "Le champ {*field*} doit contenir au minimum {length} caractères",
numeric: "Le champ {*field*} ne peut contenir que des chiffres",
oneOf: "Le champ {*field*} doit être une valeur valide",
regex: "Le champ {*field*} est invalide",
required: "Le champ est obligatoire",
required_if: "Le champ {*field*} est obligatoire lorsque {target} possède cette valeur",
size: "Le champ {*field*} doit avoir un poids inférieur à {size}KB",
double: "Le champ {*field*} doit être une décimale valide"
}
});